# Was there a serious campaign of women wanting to free bleed their periods in response to a 4chan prank?

Tags: hygiene

[Knowyourmeme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/free-bleeding) tells about this prank and how some women started some protests for being able to free bleed<sup>*</sup> their periods. It shows some twitter tweets about defending this practice.

This other pages somehow show that, at least in theory, the campaign was continued to at least a seemingly acceptable degree:

[Cbc.ca](http://www.cbc.ca/life/wellness/free-the-period-why-some-women-choose-to-free-bleed-1.4015740)

[Free Bleeding facebook group](https://www.facebook.com/FreeBleeding/)

[Spectator.co.uk](https://www.spectator.co.uk/2015/08/free-bleeding-and-the-stupidly-clever-feminists-who-fell-for-it/)

[Bustle.com](https://www.bustle.com/articles/109552-what-is-free-bleeding-what-you-need-to-know-about-the-controversial-menstruation-movement)

This makes the fact that the campaign was serious, with lots of women participating in it, and not a continuation of the prank pretty possible, but on the other hand I find that asking for free bleeding a period is something let's say... unhygienic, dirty and smelly, so wanting to do it would be strange from my point of view.

Claim clarified due to request :

Was there a serious campaign in which at least thousands of women participated (what I consider a serious campaign) for their right to free bleed their period being the origin of the protest the prank done by 4chan which is indicated in the first linked article? I mean even if the campaign existed somehow before and wasn't a prank, it suddenly turned big from that event.

<sup>* The practice of abstaining from using feminine hygiene products during menstruation</sup>

Comment: Which link says "thousands"?

Comment: This isn'tt in any link it's about my claim of being a serious campaign, which for me to be serious at least it most involve at least few thousands of people, from these links it cannot be infered more than some women supposedly participated on it, but if only these women participated it would be strange it would make to the news and there wouldn't be lots of links about that protest.

Comment: some people consider using underwear like this: https://menstrualcupreviews.net/best-period-panties-reviews/ as part of the free bleeding movement https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Bleeding_Movement If you count that, sure there are thousands.